# Win XP Pro administrator can see Capture NX2 upgrade, user can't

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

Capture NX2 software v2.3 (Nikon) was installed on Win XP pro. Nikon released an update (2.6) which was installed via the admin account. However, the upgrade is not visible to the user account. Full uninstall has been done, cleaned out registry and reinstalled but still the same problem. Admin has NX2 (v2.6), user has NX(v2.3) Nikon are unable to help, does anyone have a solution to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the install as that user, but with elevated privileges. Navigate to the setup program, right click, and choose "Run as", and run it as an administrator on the local computer.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305780